# Hiding div that contains specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, hide, contains

I've been trying to hide divs that contain  particular string using the other solutions suggested on this site, however none worked (most likely due to my inexperience with jQuery)

I'd like to completely hide all divs that (in this example) contain the string 'zynthesized'

```html
<div class="photos-wrapper" id="detailPhoto-977355202965894535_11842652">
            <div class="pseudo">
            <a href="#/user/11842652/">zynthesized</a>
        </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <a href="#/detail/977355202965894535_11842652" class="lienPhotoGrid"><img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/11195725_518243828313545_1133319712_n.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="activites">
        <span class="popular_picto ss-star "></span>
        <div class="album-relative detail-photo-album-977355202965894535_11842652" style="display: none;">
            <input type="hidden" class="apalbumsPhoto" value="977355202965894535_11842652">
            <input type="hidden" class="apalbumsPhoto-977355202965894535_11842652" value="">
        </div>
        <span class="nb_comment_score">0</span>
        <span class="comment_picto ss-chat"></span>
        <span class="nb_like_score">4</span>
                    <a href="#" class="like_picto_unselected likeAction ss-heart gridLike" id="like-977355202965894535_11842652"></a>
        </div>
    <div class="nouveau-commentaire">
      <textarea id="comment-977355202965894535_11842652" class="textareaCommentaire" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea>
      <a href="#" class="commentAction ss-chat" id="postComment-977355202965894535_11842652"></a>
      <img src="http://static.iconosquare.com/images/loading.gif" class="commentLoading">
    </div>
</div>
```

From what I've seen something like

```js
$('.photos-wrapper:contains("zynthesized")').hide()
```

Should be closest to what I need, but I've had no luck with it.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: hide `a` which contains that particular word or any child of `.photos-wrapper` that contains that word??

Comment: So what doesn't work as you expect it? Are you calling this snippet at least once element(s) available in the DOM?

Comment: Your statement does exactly what you describe. What's the problem?

Comment: When I put the script in TamperMonkey it doesn't seem to work at all. The script is set to active and set for the correct webpages (http://iconosquare.com/*) but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys! Turns out that the script was working however as the page loaded new divs automatically when scrolling, the script had to be run after the page loaded them.

The final script looks like

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    $(".photos-wrapper:contains('zynthesized')").hide();  
});  

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 150;             

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
        $(".photos-wrapper:contains('zynthesized')").hide();
    }
});
```

Hopefully this helps anyone looking to do something similar!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a regex.

```
<script>
    var ptrn = /zynthesized/g;

    $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
      if(ptrn.test($( this ).text())){
        $( this ).hide();
      }
    });
</script>
```

Here is simple snippet : [jsfiddle.net/dariubs/hgbm3doa](https://jsfiddle.net/dariubs/hgbm3doa/)

Comment: This works in jsfiddle perfectly but when I try to use it through TamperMonkey it doesn't work in practice. I feel like I must be missing something super obvious. here is how it appears `$(document).ready(function () {
    var ptrn = /zynthesized/g;

    $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log( index + ": " + "" );

      if(ptrn.test($( this ).text())){
        $( this ).hide();
      }
    });
});`