# Hide main div in which sub div contains specific text

Tags: html, hide, userscripts

I'm trying to make my first Tampermoney script

Here's an example of an html page :

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    "Hello world"
  </div>
  <div class="n">
    "Test"
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="d">
    <div class="e">
      ...
        <div class="n">
          "Hello world"
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found this topic, very interesting, but I'm not able to make it fits my requirements : [Hiding div that contains specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026469/hiding-div-that-contains-specific-string)

I would like to hide the divs class="a" ONLY if it contains a div class="n" that contains the text "Hello world".
Do I need to loop on all the divs class="a", to seek for a class="n" containing "Hello world" ? I'll need some help please...

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    "Hello world"
  </div>
  <div class="n">
    "Test"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply hide the class n $('.n').hide(); [ ttps://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/kqd0pav0/ ] is that you looking ??

Comment: This would only hide the class "n" div, I want the class "a" div to be hidden IF it contains a class "n" div WITH "Hello World", is it more clear :-/ ?

Comment: Please Check The Answer If its wrong let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. And you want if class .a contain .n with text("hello world") , .a need to be hide. I just make edit your HTML part and also comment out which div will be hide. According to your HTML first one will be not hide because .n contain "test".
 if any question or if you found anything wrong on my answer ask me. :)  [Live On Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/pwtf1nbt/1/)

**UPDATE:** In your Code the problem in your parent div you have 5 class _5jmm, _5pat, _3lb4, m_95yeui-j, _x72 but you write in jQuery closest('.5jmm _5pat _3lb4 m_95yeui-j _x72').hide(). So you can set only one class which is closest. And you don't

```js
    
 $(window).on('load', function() {
   $('._5g-l:contains("Publication suggérée")').closest('._5jmm').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<div data-fte="1" data-ftr="1" class="_5jmm _5pat _3lb4 m_95yeui-j _x72" id="hyperfeed_story_id_581d0a6f0b12a3832990101" data-testid="fbfeed_story" [...]>
  <div class="_4-u2 mbm _5v3q _4-u8" id="u_jsonp_2_1f">
    <div class="_3ccb _4-u8" [...]>
      <div></div>
      <div class="userContentWrapper _5pcr" role="article" aria-label="Actualité">
        <div class="_1dwg _1w_m">
          <div class="_5g-l"><span>Publication suggérée</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jaggana The load() method was deprecated[ one that has been outdated] in jQuery version 1.8 and removed in version 3.0. Edit my answer you can try thus

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, I think it needs a few ajustements...
Here's my code :

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('._5g-l:contains("Publication suggérée")').closest('._5jmm _5pat _3lb4 m_95yeui-j _x72').hide();
});
```

The web page :

[image]

And the associated code :

```
<div data-fte="1" data-ftr="1" class="_5jmm _5pat _3lb4 m_95yeui-j _x72" id="hyperfeed_story_id_581d0a6f0b12a3832990101" data-testid="fbfeed_story" [...]>
    <div class="_4-u2 mbm _5v3q _4-u8" id="u_jsonp_2_1f">
        <div class="_3ccb _4-u8" [...]>
            <div></div>
            <div class="userContentWrapper _5pcr" role="article" aria-label="Actualité">
                <div class="_1dwg _1w_m">
                    <div class="_5g-l"><span>Publication suggérée</span></div>
    [...]
```

Also, I can't put in the webpage :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

When I try to execute the commande in the console :

```
$('._5g-l:contains("Publication suggérée")').closest('._5jmm _5pat _3lb4 m_95yeui-j _x72').hide();
(unknown) Uncaught Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","._5g-l:contains(\"Publication suggérée\")"]]]>
    at h (https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yZ/r/AveNRnydIl_.js:36:166)
    at i (https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yZ/r/AveNRnydIl_.js:36:293)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```